# Start menu icons not changing after icon change

Tags: icons, windows-10, shortcut, clear-cache

I made a program that makes an icon and saves it to a file that is set as the icon of some shortcut files on desktop and start menu in Windows 10. After making a new icon and writing it to that file I used `SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST, nil, nil);` to refresh the icons. It works well on desktop and the icon of shortcut on the desktop changes, but the icon of shortcut in start menu does not changes. (Even the icon of the program in the task bar changes). Is there any solution?
I also tested `SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETICONS, 0, nil, SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);` but it does not works.
I think the icons cache must be forced to refresh, but how?